# Is object() == object() guaranteed to be False?

Tags: python, language-lawyer

Suppose I create two instances of class `object`. Are these two instances guaranteed to be not equal to each other? In other words, is `object() == object()` guaranteed to be `False`, or is it implementation-dependent?

I understand that `object() is object()` is guaranteed to be `False`, but here I am asking about `object() == object()`.

Comment: does it impact any business logic/architecture design?

Comment: Most of the time I'd expect it to be `True`, because default initialization should produce an object with a consistent value.

Comment: You might want to read https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__, I guess.

Comment: @MarkRansom Does `object() == object()` return `True` in the implementation you are using? Which implementation/version of Python are you using?

Comment: You realize, of course, that `object` isn't a reserved word, and could be reassigned to change the behaviour... right?

Comment: @j1-lee wow, that information is extraordinarily hard to find.  I thought it would be a quick Google away, but I wasn't able to dig it up on my own.

Comment: @Flux I checked after I left my comment, and indeed it returns `False`.  It wasn't clear to me at first that you were talking about the built-in type `object`, I thought you were speaking more generically.  You now have an answer that explains it, and I must admit the default implementation breaks my expectations.

Comment: Where is `object() is object()` guaranteed to be `False`?

Comment: @KellyBundy The documentation for `object()` says: "Return a **new** featureless object."

Comment: @Flux Right, but `is` tests for an object’s identity, which is determined using the `id()` function, and `id(object()) == id(object())` [can be `True`](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v6AoM69EIzNFIz8pKzW5RENTU8HWVgGZr/n/PwA), so why not also `object() is object()`? I think that's more difficult to explain than simply looking up what `object.__eq__` does :-P

Comment: @KellyBundy I have posted a follow up question: [Why are two instances of "object" considered non-identical although their "id()" are the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71446096/why-are-two-instances-of-object-considered-non-identical-although-their-id)

Comment: @Flux Oh I hope you didn't ask for me, as I knew the answer. I really just meant that it's more difficult to fully explain, and what juanpa said there still leaves a question: where is it guaranteed that the two objects in `object() is object()` have overlapping lifetimes? It seems obvious that they do/must, but I don't know a piece of documentation saying so, and I'm not even sure there is one :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it is guaranteed that `object() == object()` is `False` because it is [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) that "by default, `object` implements `__eq__()` by using `is`".

Comment: Now we just need proof that `is` is guaranteed to be `False` there.

Comment: @KellyBundy I would say no: "For immutable types, operations that compute new values may actually return a reference to any existing object with the same type and value, while for mutable objects this is not allowed." Then, "after `c = []; d = []`, `c` and `d` are guaranteed to refer to two different, unique, newly created empty lists." So many adjectives, yet no mention of the `id` operator. Clearly, the semantics _allow_ for the `is` comparison to return `True`, but you'd have to justify why. Those `object`s can be monkey-patched to anything, if `is` returns `True` there, it's meaningless.

Comment: @Nearoo Hmm, I don't think anybody here was talking about monkey-patching anything or so. Think of a script doing nothing but `print(object() == object())` or nothing but `print(object() is object())`.

Comment: @KellyBundy But if you return True there you have to think about other situations. What if the objects are monkey patched after the comparsion? If you return true for `object() == object()`, you should return `True` for the monkey patch case as well, or you have to setup rules that will lie between cumbersome and undecidable to enforce both for the programmer and the compiler.

Comment: @Nearoo Hmm, somewhere there you lost me, I don't understand what you're saying. But "monkey patched after the comparsion" sounds like you're talking about them being two separate objects that keep on living, so you've already *decided* against the `is` comparison possibly returning true.

Answer (score 3):

Each Python 3.x release is intended to be backward-compatible with previous 3.x releases. As it's the base class, changing the comparison behavior of `object` would break this backward compatibility promise. So I think you can rely on it, but if we knew what you're trying to do that requires this invariant, we could probably give better advice.

You can always use `assert` to make sure it continues to be true.

Comment: "if we knew what you're trying to do that requires this invariant, we could probably give better advice" - Thank you for the response. I am not trying to do anything in particular. I am simply asking out of curiosity.